# Facing issues while using blender 3.6 and 3.6LTS

Tags: rendering

I use Ryzen 5700x and Intel ARC A750 but in Blender 3.6 and 3.6LTS I am facing a issue .That is when rendering a frame or a vedio or while using render mode for first time in viewport . The problem is when render a sentence is shown in the top middle corner.It is ( ***loading render kernels. It may take a few minutes***). This problem slow down my renders . If i use 3.5 ,i can't use embree API . Pls tell a a way to fix this problem

Point to be noted that: I don't face the issue in Blender 3.5 and the render is also pretty much faster

Comment: There are no Blender developers here and no-one here has connection with the Blender Foundation. If you believe that you've found a bug, report it via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.

Comment: This message should  appear only on first use. It should not appear again, when rendering on the same installation.. is it happening repeatedly, after letting it finish?